# Webview Box-Shadow rendering issue

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, box-shadow

I have a simple standard webview in my android app and when loading a web site the box-shadows are not showing up. It just shows all elements without box-shadow. However, android chrome browser shows all box-shadows with no issue.

here below i attached two screenshots from my webview and android chrome browser that shows the map box-shadow is perfectly rendered in chrome.

[image]

[image]

Kind Regards
Ramin

Answer (score 1):

Can you please attach an image so that I can give you a better answer.

As I guess the shadow is not forming due to lower API level. You should at least use Android lollipop as minimum to get the shadow effect.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I updated minSdkVersion to 21 and did not resolve the issue. I attached pictures above for your reference too.

Comment: If I am not wrong you are trying to implement shadow in the map.

Then, I have one suggestion.
Please use card view to get a drop shadow for your webview. That will be very easy to use. 
Also use wrap content in cardview&amp;#39;s layout height and width to make it work perfectly.

Please let me know what happens

Comment: Hi Vishal, if you meant to wrap the webview in the cardview then i did and did not resolve the issues.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I thought that the map box is just webview and rest of the items are Android button and text. It's all clear now. Now I understand what your are actually trying to say.

See, if a feature works in chrome and doesn't works in webview, then it completely depends upon how the website's code is written. It couldn't be solved by writing codes in Android. The main thing is, at least it is properly displaying there.

I hope I have cleared the confusion. If my answer has helped you, then please approve it :)

Comment: sorry, I did not understand your point. If the android chrome browser is showing fine and webveiw is not then it is website coding issue? I think it is otherwise ...

Comment: If you are sure that this is not a website code problem, then I have one more thing to explain here.

See, webview isn't chrome. They both are two different applications. When you use webview you ask the inbuilt system webview app to perform a particular function inside your app. There are still many bugs in webview and it should be solved in future. One of the bugs which I know it's when you full screen a video in webview, sometimes the device hangs, or only the audio plays etc. So, this could possibly be another webview bug. 

Hope, I have cleared your confusion. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Thanks to let me know I helped. Please approve the answer so that other can easily get to conclusion :)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow, Android Webview's support of `inset` is implemented with the vendor prefix: `-webkit-`

So I guess you need to use `-webkit-box-shadow`.